# JavaScript hoisting confusion regarding let

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaration, referenceerror, hoisting

```
a= 10; console.log(a); let a; => Cannot access 'a' before initialization
```

above code gives error for initialization, even if **a** is declared before use. Please explain how this gives an error if a is already hoisted and get declared "a=10" before using it.

That also means if a variable is declared with let or const, hoisting doesn't have any practical impact ?

if I run below code

```
let a; console.log(a); => undefined
```

in this case I am able to print a i.e. undefined,  without initializing it.

What is happening in core ?

Comment: The problem is not with the `console.log(a)`, it's with `a = 10`. Try this: `a = 10; let a;` and you will get the same error. This happens because the compiler thinks the `a` in `a = 10` refers to the `a` in `let a`, that is, it thinks you try to use `a` before its declaration by `let a`.

Comment: thnks! I read about tdz and it helped understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

When you type:

```
a=10
```

then you are defining a global variable. It is deprecated and not recommended style of coding in almost all languages.

To prevent declaring global variables es6 introduced `let` and `const`.

Now when you are using `let` or `const` your interpreter checks that when you typing

```
let a;
```

you do not have `a` used before this declaration. This is the reason for the error.

---

Update:

You typed:

```
let a; console.log(a); => undefined
```

it is ok because `a` is `declared`, memory is reserved, the symbol `a` is registered, but the value is not assigned, so when you evaluate the value assigned to symbol `a` it is `undefined`.

Please compare it with case:

```
console.log(c);
```

You will get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined
```

because the symbol `c` was never declared.

Now when you will assign values to `a` it will be done in local scope, but when you will assign values to `c` it will create global variables.

---

To improve your understanding please read about all methods of defining variables and look at all edge cases. A great article is under the link:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Comment: when we use 'let a ;' does it overrides the gloabal 'a' and removes it ?? also why when 'let a;' at top initializes 'a' with 'undefined' but when hoisting is done its not initialized with undefined ?

Comment: let was introduced to prevent usage `a` before declaring it by `let`.

Comment: Let was not override and remove other variables. You can see it as syntax that ensures the programmer to write well-designed code, so you will see an error when in time of declaring by let there is declared `a`.

Comment: thanks! for answering it helped in clearing a confusion.